# How do I nudge my coworker to reframe his mindset from 'me' to 'we'

Tags: work-environment, coworkers

I just joined a new company. My immediate coworker, who's also been assigned at my line manager, takes a lot of pride in the work he's done. Even when it came to my onboarding and in general, I notice that he likes to talk about himself and all the good things he has done for the company and the issues he overcame with other people who used to work here.

Although this does raise some red flags, I just want to focus on gaining the knowledge and information to do my new role. but I'm finding it really hard to keep him on track. If I put it to him bluntly he will probably be offended and will hold a grudge against me. How can I communicate to him that he should primarly focus on team spirit?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far to get him to focus? How do you react now when he goes off track?

Comment: i have mentioned to him to zoom out and to look at things in a 'grand scheme of things' perspective. This did help a bit during that conversation. but not since

Comment: Hi BlueOcean, welcome to IPS. I've given your post an edit, hopefully to improve it by removing the unclear question at the end, and rephrased the main idea conveyed by the body of the post to keep it on-topic. Is that OK with you? You can also rollback to previous state.

Comment: You could ask this on https://workplace.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why is this even a problem? Please elaborate with an example.